# There is a way to start a rails server changing the access address?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to simulate an error on my rails application.

In my running application I have the following address: **net1/redmine/projects/**

When I'm going to simulate this in my machine, the command `rails s` start my server on **localhost:3000/projects/**

There is a way to start the server changing the address like for example: test1/redmine/projects? How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the route of your specific page you can change it in `routes.rb`. If you want to change the `IP` and `PORT` on which you serve your application, you can do: `rails s -b $IP -p $PORT`.

Answer (score 0):

In what way would you need to use the net1/redmine/projects/ address?

I would instead of changing servers adress, change the the above address to your local host in your test cases.

What I mean is that in your test, u change that used address to local host via a stubbing or override if that is what you need.

This way, all your testing is done with local host as address but your live version still has original address.